# How much would an AT-AT Imperial Walker cost?

Tags: weapons

In the Star Wars universe, the AT-AT Imperial Walker is mid sized military vehicle used by the Empire. It is manufactured and operated for inter-planetary missions.

The Question: "How much would it cost to build an AT-AT Imperial Walker?"

Comment: A lot. Probably millions in research and development trying to solve that pesky "easily tripped and destroyed by wrapping a cable around it's legs problem"

Comment: @apaul34208 I know, right?! I mean, "AT-AT" stands for "All Terrain Armored Transport" but it almost couldn't be any less "all terrain"! One word: "hover", like almost every other vehicle in the Star Wars universe. XD

Comment: While they're at it, they might invest in [better targeting and training](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/95/04/ff/9504ff18081fa4306d16e06c6acf407f.jpg). XD

Comment: [It varies](https://www.google.com/search?q=at-at+imperial+walker&rmd=sivn&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix_LTZg_3QAhWJ3YMKHRroCtcQ_AUIBygB&biw=800&bih=1280)

Comment: Updates: the cost had gone up ten folds because version 2 can untie shoelaces...

Comment: The ones from the 80s probably cost more than the ones in the special edition. Ask George Lucas.

Comment: Dr Evil will sell you an AT:AT for *one million dollars*

Answer (score 5):

### It depends on who you ask, but usually a lot.

A google search for "how much would an AT-AT cost" provides all the information to your question on about seven sites. While Worldbuilding may be a good place to get answers, people have worked this out already, and that information is in the public domain.

#### [bestcasino.co.uk](http://www.bestcasino.co.uk/cost-of-building-AT-AT/) estimates `$226.5 million dollars`

They factor in the costs of weapons, defenses, construction, joints, motors, and paying the crew.

#### [A guy on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-much-would-it-realistically-cost-to-build-an-Imperial-AT-AT-Walker/answer/Kynan-Eng) estimates `$196 million dollars`

He factors in the costs of construction, the cost of materials, and that of generating electricity.

#### [A robotics expert in Malibu](http://www.livescience.com/13785-imperial-walker-america.html) estimates `> 100 million dollars`

His calculations are based on structural strength, weapons systems, and maintaining joints.

Answer (score 3):

### It Depends

- Labor costs: depends on whether you hire sentient species like [Ugnaughts](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ugnaught) or [Jawas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jawa), or go for automated droid-based production. Sentients might have labor union costs
- Haggling could effect final cost. Perhaps contract an expert haggler?
- If you have any [nova crystals](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Currency), you might be able to get a better deal
- Do you buy used parts or only new OEM parts?
- Are you buying wholesale or retail?
- Are you buying 1 or a many? If you get more than one, you might get a discount
- If you have a special relationship with the seller, you might get a better deal than you would otherwise
- If you buy used parts, do you skimp and use overworked, underpaid  [Jakku scavengers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Scavenger), or do you buy from a reputable Imperial dealer?
- You could just put it on the Emperor's tab (if you've got the clout)
- Perhaps you could get a better deal via a [black market](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Black_market)
- Might be best to deal only with a reputable dealer, but that'll drive the price up for sure. But, NEVER buy directly from the Empire--you'll pay through the nose for the showroom saleperson's commission
- Do you pay all at once or pay in installments with interest?
- Cost for extended warranty could increase the price, depending on how many decades you extend for, and if you opt for accidental damage coverage
- Do you mine the materials directly, or do you use recycled materials?
- Are you buying an AT-AT the very first day they are unveiled, or years later when they're an older model of troop transport? You'll certainly pay top dollar if you're buying at it's premire unveiling at the galactic arms dealers expo, as opposed to decades later when they're old, outdated transporter tech
- Do you pick it up directly and save on shipping, or do you splurge and have it delivered?
- How soon do you need it? Second day delivery for a hastily conceived raid? Or have you planned ahead and can afford to wait 6 to 8 weeks for delivery?
- If you opt for shipping, do you pay for insurance in case the shipment gets hijacked by scruffy-looking, nerf-herding [space "pirates"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nerf_herder)? Or worse yet, gets lost in shipping and ends up lost in a bog on some backwater swamp planet in the [Sluis sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagobah)

### That Being Said

Modern military crafts have a wide range of prices. Take fighter jets for example. According to [list prices on the internet](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2015/06/07/fighter-jet-worlds-top-10-best-sellers.aspx) they can range from \$400 million dollars to just under \$20 million each:

- F-22 Raptor stealth fighter -- widely considered the most capable air superiority combat jet in the world: $412 million apiece
- Fourth-generation F/A-18 or F-15 fighter jets: about $100 million each
- Soviet-era Sukhoi Su-34: $18 million
- Domestic Scorpion: $17 million

This is just for the plane. I would imagine a machine significantly larger might cost more, but then again, if the tech involved is mostly just armored shell and hydraulics, maybe they aren't top of the line price tag.

### Operating Cost

In addition to the machinery itself, there is also the operating cost. For modern fighter jets, it costs \$18,000 an hour to fly an Air Force F-15 or F-22 fighter jet, but only \$3,000 per hour to fly a Scorpion. So, operating cost will come into play with the ultimate cost of the AT-AT too.

### Conclusion

Although many of these things sound kind of silly because they sound like how we do sales transactions on earth today over tiny little electronics or cars, the same general mechanics can easily be imagined to apply to any purchase of military equipment. If money still exists, then the technicalities of financial infrastructures probably still exist too.

So, it's really hard to say exactly how much it'd cost, due to the overwhelming number of factors.